# Error while building project using maven [com/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCCompilationUnit]

Tags: java, maven-3, lombok

I am trying to use maven to build my java project, but I always get the error message,

```
> Execution default of goal org.projectlombok:lombok-maven-plugin:1.18.10.0:delombok failed: A required class was missing while executing org.projectlombok:lombok-maven-plugin:1.18.10.0:delombok: com/sun/tools/javac/tree/JCTree$JCCompilationUnit
```

I used Java8, maven3. Does anyone know how to fix such issue?

Comment: Check here its a similar issue:  https://github.com/awhitford/lombok.maven/issues/23

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Sorry, I think I fixed this issue finally. The mistake I made was that I pointed to JAVA_HOME to the JRE directory. After re-direct JAVA_HOME to the JDK directory, this issue is fixed.

Comment: The newest Jdks does not have a JRE folder. I setup JDK 21 as JAVA_HOME, and encountered the `same exception` when building Quarkus application.

Answer (score 4):

In intelij, `Setting>Build>Java compiler>` & `Project setting>`  fix `JDK` version

Answer (score 0):

for me the issue was on mac. My JAVA_HOME was pointing to `/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home`

try running

```
mvn -version
```

and if the java home used by maven is different then try exporting JAVA_HOME to your ~/.bash_profile or ~/.zshrc etc. Depending on whatever you are using.

```
export JAVA_HOME=/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/openjdk-17.jdk/Contents/Home
```

For me this was the only issue. Adding in case someone is struggling with this on console.

**Note: Your JAVA_HOME will depend upon your java version, operating system so change the path accordingly. Please avoid copy pasting.**

Answer (score 0):

If you are facing this issue in IntelliJ,

Check the java version,

- Click on File -> Project Structure
- select the required jdk version you are using in your project and click ok and apply it

[image]